# Append to the first line with batch

Tags: batch-file

I feel dump sorry for the bother

I'm trying to get a line added to the first line in a txt file and I can't figure this out

I did this and got it to work on the last line

```
@echo off

for %%i in (*.txt) do >>%%i echo Message
```

This is what I have in the txt file

```
{ < -- Old line 1
Funtimes
Greattimes
```

What I'm trying to do is this

```
SUPER < --New Line 1
{
    Funtimes
    Greattimes
```

What I get is this at the end

```
} <-- Last line in my txt file
Super <br>
```

I actually need both top and bottom message (Super) 
So far I can only get the bottom 
and I need the `(*.txt)` since I have many txt files

I tired doing several different ways and nothing

```
echo message > newfilename.txt and

echo "my line" > newFile.txt
type newfile.txt myOriginalFile.txt > myOriginalFile.txt
```

Thanks for the answer but for some reason my script and the answer script both give a space

```
)Super
-empty space-
```

I actually needed the `Super` under the `)` and I have fixed that so now I get this

```
)
Super
-empty space-
```

This script was provided to me and works great in the when it's directly in the folder with the txt files

```
@echo off

for %%i in (*.txt) do (
     >"%%i.tmp" echo.First line
    >>"%%i.tmp" type "%%i"
    >>"%%i.tmp" echo.Last line
    del "%%i"
    ren "%%i.tmp" "%%i"
)
```

This works great, but I have many folders and subs so I made a change and now this stopped working

```
ren "%%i.tmp" "%%i"
```

This is the updated script

```
@echo off

FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir  /a-d /b /s "*.txt"') do (
     >"%%i.tmp" echo.First Line
    >>"%%i.tmp" type "%%i"
    >>"%%i.tmp" echo ,
    >>"%%i.tmp" echo.Last Line
    del "%%i"
    ren "%%i.tmp" "%%i"
)
```

So now it edits the files like it need to, but it fails it does not rename it back

In order to work around the issue I have made 2 other scripts I would like to see what else I need to do to fix the `ren`

I was told to add this `%%~nxi` but I can't get it to work I have tried this and a few other and nothing any idea where it goes

```
FIX:
ren "%%i.tmp" "%%~nxi"
```

Thanks

Comment: @Stephan - So I I'm confused on what to rename I tried several changes and nothing works, I'm sure I'm placing the changes wrong, I changed many things and I can't get it to work, Do I add this to the original or changed script Like this `ren "%%i.tmp" "%%~nxi"`

Comment: `ren "%%i.tmp" "%%~nxi"` should work. As a troubleshooting step, try `echo ren "%%i.tmp" "%%~nxi"` instead, to see, if both source and destination information is correct. If this doesn't help, run the script with `echo on` and analyze the output.

Comment: @Stephan - Thank you not sure why it didn't work the first time, when you told to change it to `%%~nxi` I knew this was right `ren "%%i.tmp" "%%~nxi"` but it kept failing, now for some reason it works - Once again Thank you